# Different ways to call components inside render method [REACT-NATIVE]

Tags: react-native, textinput

I'm having some problems while I use this implementation:

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const onChangeText = useCallback((t) => setText(t), []);

  const Input = () => {
    return (
      <TextInput
        value={text}
        placeholder="dioporco"
        style={{ fontSize: 50 }}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Input />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Whenever I try to write something inside text input, after I've typed one letter the keyboard is dismissed. And this doesn't happen if, instead of , I use {Input()}.

Why this happens? What's the difference?
Tank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because each time you enter a character, you will update state, and on updating state, component rerender too.

You have a function for creating `TextInput`, when component rerender, function called again, and this cause TextInput rerender too, and react native close keyboard on rerendering.

This is important to not define your component as function in other component.

You can create separated component, or use `useMemo`

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, but if I use useMemo I have to pass text and onChangeText to the dependencies. And again, why this doesn’t happen if I call Input() as a function?

Comment: Yes, This what react do it :))) When create a function inside component, react create new instance of it on each render

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you are using functions like that, every time the component is rerendering, it will cause the entire TextInput to be rendered like it didn't exist before.
So try to create Input component (Function outside of App) and then use it in App component.

```
export function Input() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("")
  const onChangeText = useCallback((t) => setText(t), [])

  return (
    <TextInput
      value={text}
      placeholder="dioporco"
      style={{ fontSize: 50 }}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
    />
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Input />
    </View>
  );
}
```